# Winter Bash 2015

Tags: discussion

This is more of an announcement than a question.

If some of you have noticed or received a hat for your profile pic (yes, really...) this is part of Stack Exchange's network wide [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/).  Here's [our leader board for that](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)...currently I am not winning D:

Part of the point is to encourage people to think about participation, and that although answering questions is, obviously enough, fundamental, there are many other things that are important to keeping things viable, such as editing and *voting*.  Having a sufficient number of users with [various privileges](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) is about more than just hats and requires taking the time to review other people's contributions.

As I've tried to point out before, the tooltip for questions is **"This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"**.  It does not say, "This question deserves the Nobel Prize", etc. Upvoting questions that are clear, sufficiently detailed, and show an effort has already been made to understand the issue is one way of indicating, by contrast, the right and wrong way to ask for help.

The tooltip for answers is **"This answer is useful"**.  It does not say, "This answer saved *me* hours of work" or "This answer provides information I was unaware of -- thanks" (if that were the case, people who already know everything need never upvote).  If you believe an answer is useful in relation to the question, that's enough.  The reason this is important is because you probably do not have time to answer all of them yourself, so showing appreciation for the fact that someone else did may increase your chances of saving more time again later.

With regard to Winter Bash, we may be sweetening the pot a bit with 3 trips to South Wales to visit the Rpi factory. They also make chocolate truffles, so don't miss this chance.  Just kidding -- they don't make truffles and we won't be sending anyone there.  But we might still be sweetening the pot, keep your eye on meta for the next while to find out details.

Comment: Wow, there's even a leader board?

Comment: ... and yes, all hands go up for *voting*!